# ElasticSearch does not respect Max NGram length while using NGram Tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Ngram tokenizer and I have specified min_length as 3 and max_length as 5. However even if I try searching for a word of length greater than 5 , it still gives me the result.Its strange as ES will not index the combination with length 6 , but I am still able to retrieve the record.Is there any theory I am missing here? If not, what significance really does the max_length of NGram has? Following is the mapping that I tried..

```
PUT ngramtest
{
  "mappings": {
    "MyEntity":{
      "properties": {
        "testField":{
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }

    }
  }, 
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Indexed a test entity as:

```
PUT ngramtest/MyEntity/123
{
  "testField":"Z/16/000681"

}
```

AND, this query weirdly yeilds results for

```
GET  ngramtest/MyEntity/_search
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "testField": "000681"
   }
 }
}
```

I have tried this for 'analyzing' the string:

```
POST ngramtest/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "Z/16/000681."
}
```

Can someone please correct me if I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because your analyzer `my_analyzer` is used for indexing **AND**  searching. Hence, when you search for a word of 6 characters `abcdef`, that word will also be analyzed by your ngram analyzer at search time and produce the tokens `abc`, `abcd`, `abcde`, `bcd`, etc, and those will match the indexed tokens.

What you need to do is to specify that you want to use the standard analyzer as `search_analyzer` in your mapping

```
    "testField":{
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer": "standard"
    }
```

Before wiping your index and repopulating it, you can test this theory simply by specifying the search analyzer to use in your match query:

```
GET ngramtest/MyEntity/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "testField": {
        "query": "000681", 
        "analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly when I index and search with JSON , BIG thanks :). However I am yet to test this using the .NET (NEST) API, currently used in my application.I will surely accept your answer once it comes good there as well! ;)