# Ngram Tokenizer on field, not on query

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

I'm having trouble finding the solution for a use case here.
Basically, it's pretty simple : I need to perform a "contains" query, like a SQL `like '%...%'`.

I've seen there is a regexp query, which I actually managed to get working perfectly, but as it seems to scale badly, i'm trying out nGrams. Now, I've played around with them before and know "how they work", but the behaviour isn't the one I expect it to be.

Basically, i've configured my analyzer to be mingram =2, maxgram = 20. Say I index a user called "Christophe". I want the query "Chris" to actually match, which it does, since Chris is a 5-gram of Christophe. The problem is, "Risotto" matches aswell, because it gets broken down into Ngrams and ultimately "is" is a 2-gram of "Christophe" and so it matches aswell.

What I need is the analyzer to actually break down the indexed field in nGrams at indexing time, and compare those to the FULL text query. Risotto should match Risotto, XXXRisottoXXX and so on, but not Risolo or something where the nGrams do match.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543223/elasticsearch-does-not-respect-max-ngram-length-while-using-ngram-tokenizer/41543664?noredirect=1#comment70303094_41543664 (hint you need to set the `standard` analyzer for search time.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [search_analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) setting to have distinct index time and search time analyzers.

Sample from docs:

```
"mappings": {
  "my_type": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete", 
        "search_analyzer": "standard" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried out this solution, it seems to work like a charm when I input only one word, e.g. Chris for Christophe, but when I type Chris Sch he doesn't find the record Christophe Schutz. I'm using a multimatchquery on both the lastname and the firstname, and I added the search_analyzer on both fields. Any clue ?